# Using DisplayForModel with MVC4 and the ASPX View Engine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Using ASP.NET MVC4 (.NET 4, C#) on MSVC 2010 SP1, I've noticed that I can pass a class model to a view using Razor and display the model using DisplayModelFor & EditorForModel but when I try to do the same using the ASPX view engine it doesn't work. Why is that? Code snippets from my test project below. Thanks.

My Controller:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {

       public ActionResult Index()
       {

           TestModelClass c = new TestModelClass();
           c.MyInt = 999;
           return View(c);
    }
}
```

My Model:

```
namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class TestModelClass
    {
        public int MyInt { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My View:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#"       Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication1.Models.TestModelClass>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <%Html.DisplayForModel(); %>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternate Razor (Works):

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.TestModelClass

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@Html.DisplayForModel()
```

Successful output from Razor version:

Index 
MyInt 
999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a `:`.

The correct syntax should be

```
<%: Html.DisplayForModel() %>
```

Comment: `;` is not obsolete. It's an alternative syntax which is directly writing to the output stream instead of buffering it in memory.

Comment: Wow, really? You never stop learning. I will correct my answer. Thank you. Is that documented somewhere?